# Ubuntu 18.10 Xorg Server Error Logout

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, intel, 18.10, logout

I recently built a new PC and installed Ubuntu 18.10. I am having issues with being logged out and returning to the login after opening certain Applications (Settings, Handbrake etc).

Logging in via `startx` and attempting to open these applications results in a similar logout with the following Xorg Error Stack Trace:

```
[    12.456] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x55eeaa7b4229]
[    12.456] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x50) [0x7f54784ace1f]
[    12.456] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f54782ef077]
[    12.456] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0x121) [0x7f54782d0535]
[    12.456] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[    12.456] (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (?+0x0) [0x7f54782d0400]
[    12.457] (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__assert_fail+0x42) [0x7f54782e0142]
[    12.457] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRIMoveBuffersHelper+0xc43) [0x55eeaa77f933]
[    12.457] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2Authenticate+0xa2) [0x55eeaa780f42]
[    12.457] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2GetParam+0x75b) [0x55eeaa7820cb]
[    12.457] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x35e) [0x55eeaa65597e]
[    12.457] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3b6) [0x55eeaa659906]
[    12.457] (EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xeb) [0x7f54782d209b]
[    12.457] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x55eeaa64367a]
[    12.457] (EE)
[    12.457] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    12.457] (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
[    12.457] (EE)
[    12.457] (EE)
```

it appears modifying the `.Xauthority` permissions from `-rw-------` to `-rwxrwxrwx` prevents the logouts from occurring temporarily. After being logged out,`.Xauthority` permissions are reset to `-rw-------`

Computer specs

```
Intel 9900k - Using Oboard Graphics
Asus Z390 Mobo
Samsung Pro 970
Corsair Vengeance DDR4
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same problem with the 9900k and ubuntu 18.10.

Using the mesa packages available from the ppa
ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
fixed it for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

and reboot or restart Xorg.

Answer (score -1):

I got the correct drivers for RTX2070 in Ubuntu 18.04 using

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Reference: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux